# How do you scale a dynamic textfield in flash from the center point using as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I'm trying to make a text effect where on every frame the textfield increases in size and decreases in opacity.  I'm using the scaleX and scaleY properties of my dynamic textfield to enlarge, but it's doing so keeping the left registration point fixed.  I want to make it scale up radially outward, or with the center point fixed.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a wrapper for the `TextField` (i.e. a Sprite containing the `TextField`) to enforce the registration point to the middle. If the TextField is dynamic make sure it's `autoSize` is set to `LEFT`. Thereafter you can just set it's `x/y` position to `-textField.width*.5/-textField.height*.5`. Of course the scaling should be applied to the parent.

Comment: Putting it in a Sprite and setting the reg point to the middle was the easiest fix for me.  Thanks to all for the great answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
 textfield.x -= textfield.width /2;
 textfield.y -= textfield.height /2;
```

if the x and y are 0 this will help

Comment: I'd do `>> 1` instead of `/ 2` so you don't mess up the anti-aliasing by being on a fractional pixel. That said, since he's gonna scale it right after anyway, probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing pretty much exactly that right now. I am using a wrapper a Theo.T mentions.

This is my code (most of it):

```
private function drawText(str:String, size:int = 16, px:int = 0, py:int = 0):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana", size, _textcolor);
    tf.align = "center";
    var _txt:TextField = new TextField();
    _txt.embedFonts = true;
    _txt.wordWrap = true;
    _txt.selectable = false;
    _txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    _txt.antiAliasType = "advanced";
    _txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
    _txt.width = _textwidth;
    _txt.text = str;
    _txt.x = -_txt.width / 2;
    mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = _scalemin;
    mc.x = px;
    mc.y = py;
    mc.addChild(_txt);
    addChild(mc);
    startMove(mc);
}

private function moveText(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
    if (mc.scaleX >= _scalemax) {
        mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = _scalemax;
    } else if (mc.y > _ymin) {
        mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY *= _scalegrow;
    }
    if (mc.alpha <= 0.1) {
        mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveText);
        mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code mga posted above and it works.  I am posting the entire thing here, as it took me a little time to figure out exactly what to do.  What I noticed is that I needed to NOT embed the fonts to get it to work.  I'd like to know why?  Anyway, this works for me:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class LearningScrollingMain extends MovieClip {
    private var _scalemax:Number = 20;
    private var _ymin:Number = 10;
    private var _scalegrow:Number =1.05;
    private var _scalemin:Number=1;

    public function LearningScrollingMain() {
        drawText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", 24, 400, 200);
    }

    private function drawText(str:String, size:int, px:int, py:int):void {
        var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        tf.align = "center";
        tf.size=size;
        var _txt:TextField = new TextField();
        _txt.defaultTextFormat=tf;
//        _txt.embedFonts = true;
        _txt.wordWrap = false;
        _txt.selectable = false;
        _txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
        _txt.antiAliasType = "advanced";
        _txt.text = str;
        _txt.x = -_txt.width / 2;
        _txt.y = -_txt.height / 2;
        mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = _scalemin;
        mc.x = px;
        mc.y = py;
        mc.addChild(_txt);
        addChild(mc);
        startMove(mc);
    }

    private function startMove(mc:MovieClip):void {
        mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveText);
    }

    private function moveText(e:Event):void {
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
        if (mc.scaleX >= _scalemax) {
            mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = _scalemax;
        } else if (mc.y > _ymin) {
            mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY *= _scalegrow;
        }
        if (mc.alpha <= 0.1) {
            mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveText);
            mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
        }
    }
}
}
```